# Multicast source address changed

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I have a problem with udp multicast setup. In my network there are 2 nodes. One of them (one) is sending multicast messages and another one (two) is receiving them. But this another one do actually get invalid source address. Instead having source address of sender it has source address of gateway...

Do maybe anyone knows what could be the reason ? Where should I look for ?

UDP dump from host one:

```
09:25:24.764828 IP hcp2.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:25:24.975521 IP pawel-VirtualBox.1479 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:25:25.767102 IP hcp2.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:25:25.977016 IP pawel-VirtualBox.1479 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:25:26.767626 IP hcp2.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:25:26.978852 IP pawel-VirtualBox.1479 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
```

UDP dump from host two:

```
09:23:52.394689 IP pawel-VirtualBox.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:23:52.708088 IP hcp1.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:23:53.396603 IP pawel-VirtualBox.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:23:53.712247 IP hcp1.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:23:54.399210 IP pawel-VirtualBox.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:23:54.715468 IP hcp1.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:23:55.401720 IP pawel-VirtualBox.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
09:23:55.717677 IP hcp1.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
```

UDP dump from gateway:

```
11:15:11.901090 IP 192.168.0.122.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:12.154542 IP 192.168.0.121.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:12.902251 IP 192.168.0.122.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:13.155161 IP 192.168.0.121.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:13.905122 IP 192.168.0.122.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:14.156675 IP 192.168.0.121.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:14.911502 IP 192.168.0.122.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:15.158170 IP 192.168.0.121.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
11:15:15.912754 IP 192.168.0.122.41000 > 224.224.224.245.41000: UDP, length 56
```

Comment: Can you add some further information to your question to help other understand it further?

Comment: Added, I wonder why hcp1 is  not seeing multicast source as hcp2, instead it's gateway..